# Choosing motors for quadcopter frame

Tags: quadcopter

I bought this drone frame : q450 glass fiber quadcopter frame 450mm from http://hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__49725__Q450_V3_Glass_Fiber_Quadcopter_Frame_450mm_Integrated_PCB_Version.html

I'm considering buying 4 AX-4005-650kv Brushless Quadcopter Motor's from http://hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__17922__AX_4005_650kv_Brushless_Quadcopter_Motor.html

Will these motor's fit this frame ? How can I determine what motor's will fit the frame ?

Comment: You should also take care of your propeller choice. With a 11.1V power supply, the max rpm of a 650kv motor is quiet limited, and you'll need a big propeller with high torque to be able to take off.

Answer (score 1):

Those motors have three mounting holes while the frame expects four for the the motors. So you could use an adapter like this:

[image]

Just make sure all the spacings are correct for your motrs and your frame.

The URL for your frame lists mounting holes that are spaced at 16/19mm.

Or alternatively you could look for a motor with holes that are spaced correctly to your frame without having to use adapters. You're probably better off avoiding use of the adapters as they add unnecessary weight, unless you can't find better specced motors.